# Unmanaged to managed structs

Tags: c#, marshalling

I'm receiving in `C#` a structure pointer from a `C++` library callback

`C++` structure (the packing is 1):

```
typedef 
{
    int data1[8];
    int data2[8];
    int data3;
    int data3;  
} SomeStruct;
```

in `C#` I have this equivalent:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1), Serializable]
public struct SomeStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    public int[] data1

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    public int [] data2;

    public int data3;
    public int data4;
};
```

var data contains the right `IntPtr`

```
SomeStruct ss = (SomeStruct )Marshal.PtrToStructure(pointer, typeof(SomeStruct));
```

But I'm getting garbage, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks right so far, include more code showing how you got `pointer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the simplest possible example that works, using VC++

You might want to check the following:

- is everything correct in your code ?
- are you using something else than VC++ ?

  - if so then check out the packing and alignment behavior of that compiler

**The Win32 DLL project that exports symbols:**

```
struct test
{
    int data1[8];
    int data2[8];
    int data3;
    int data4;
};

EXTERN_C MYDLL_API test* Test()
{
    test* pTest = new test;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        pTest->data1[i] = i;
        pTest->data2[i] = i;
    }
    pTest->data3 = 1234;
    pTest->data4 = 5678;
    return pTest;
}
```

**The C# test program:**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var intPtr = Test();
            var ptrToStructure = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Test1>(intPtr);
        }

        [DllImport("MyDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern IntPtr Test();
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct Test1
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public readonly int[] data1;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public readonly int[] data2;

        public readonly int data3;
        public readonly int data4;
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Still cant see the problem in my code, anyway its good to have the confirmation that the method is the right one, so thanks a lot, i will check deeply , now im sure it's some detail ovelooked.

Comment: @EduardoLista Try to focus on where your code differs - the use of `typedef` instead of `struct`, for instance, or the `Pack=1` parameter you pass to `StructLayoutAttribute`.